# Creating a VIEW using MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

```
create VIEW [Demo] as 
select TOP 999999
FROM Table1  group by column1,order by column2 ;
```

I am trying to create a VIEW Demo that should contain all the rows of Table1 and must be sorted on the basis of column2 and grouped as per column1.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing.

Comment: you can Improve your question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean: "all the rows of Table" and grouped by column1? What do you want to reach?

Comment: you may want to check the link i posted

Comment: "must be sorted on the basis of column2" - you have a fundamental misunderstanding here. Views and Tables have *no* inherent ordering that is observable.

Comment: `order by` is for "final" queries. Your view is a source for a query. Write a query that selects from your view and put `order by` there.

Answer (score 0):

When you `group by`, you need to use some aggregation function against all columns that are not included in the `group by`.

```
create VIEW [Demo] as 
select TOP 999999 column1, max(column2) as column2
FROM  Table1 
group by column1 
order by column2;
```

The other possibility is including all columns to your group by clause.

```
   create VIEW [Demo] as 
    select TOP 999999 column1,  column2
    FROM  Table1 
    group by column1, column2 
    order by column2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Views, like tables, should not presume an inherently ordered set. That is, unless an `ORDER BY` clause is specified at run time, no ordering should be implied. That said, you can do something like the following:

```
alter view foobar as
    select top(100) percent [object_id], sum(rows) as [row_count]
    from sys.partitions
    where index_id in (0, 1)
    group by [object_id]
    order by [object_id]
go
```

That is, specify `select top(100) percent` and an order by and you'll get all of the rows back in the specified order. But it's still dirty.

EDIT: It looks like this trick no longer works for top 100 percent. This is an even worse hack, but appears to work:

```
create function tvf_foobar(@pct int)
returns table
as return
    select top(@pct) percent [object_id], sum(rows) as [row_count]
    from sys.partitions
    where index_id in (0, 1)
    group by [object_id]
    order by [row_count] desc
go

select * from tvf_foobar(100)
```

But it's still a hack. If you learn nothing else from this answer, learn that you should specify an order by in the select from the object rather than trying to encapsulate it in an object; the latter isn't really the right way to do it.

Comment: "But it's still dirty." - and there's the small detail also that it *doesn't work*. It may *appear* to work here because you're using the *same* value for your `order by` as your `group by` and often, the results of a query containing `group by` will be output in that order, but even that's not guaranteed. Changing your above view to order by `row_count` and creating it on a moderate DB of mine, I got results in `object_id` order (but that wasn't guaranteed) and the first four rows counts were 1602, 275, 0 and 297 - demonstrating that the `order by` had been completely ignored.

Comment: Interesting. That _used_ to work, so they must've shored that up since last I was asked to do it. What's also interesting is that if you do something like `top(99) percent`, it appears to do the "right" thing (i.e. returns the rows in the specified order). I'll amend the post.

Comment: Stop trying to apply band aids. Anything that "appears" to work is just that - an appearance that should *not* be relied upon. People need to stop *pretending* that there is a way to have an "ordered view" - the beast does not exist.

Comment: Your previous objection was that the stated code didn't produce the stated results. Which was valid. The new code does and a look at the query plan will show why - the optimizer is leaving the sort in the plan because it can't produce a generic plan that works for all parameter values without it. And I think it's quite clear that I *still* think it's a bad idea. At some point, you have to acknowledge that people are going to shoot themselves in the foot despite your warnings. You're free to disagree with me, which is what that little down arrow that subtracts internet points is for.

Comment: Because I've already been through one cycle of this before. People *used* to rely on `TOP 100 PERCENT` because it *appeared* to work. And then a new version of SQL Server came along and those people got upset because it *stopped* working. Even when the server *does* have to apply sorting to calculate the `TOP`, it still doesn't *guarantee* that that sort order will be persisted in the final output.

Answer (score 0):

Your column2 would be either Max,Min or Count() like the below.

```
CREATE VIEW [Demo]
AS
SELECT column1
    ,Max(column2) AS Column2
    --,Min(column2) AS Column2
    --,Count(*) AS Column2
FROM Table1
GROUP BY column1
ORDER BY column2
```

Note: Please don't use Order by inside the view. If you want to do sorting do it using the view name like the below.

```
SELECT *
FROM Demo
ORDER BY Column2
```

Answer (score -1):

For [SQL view with Order by](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/order-by-in-sql-view.aspx) you can use TOP 100 Percent, for example

You can also try following [Partition By clause with Aggregation functions](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-count-function-with-partition-by-clause.aspx) for counting etc. grouped by a column

```
create view [Demo] as 
select top 100 Percent
    parent_object_id pid,
    count(name) over (partition by parent_object_id) cnt, *
from sys.all_objects
order by name
```

Comment: `TOP 100 PERCENT` stopped being an "effective" means of getting a view to sort with, I believe, the release of SQL Server 2008. It just plain *doesn't work*.

Comment: You're right. In fact tables or views can not be created ordered physically by design. In order to get a sorted resultset, developer should explicitely use ORDER BY clause after table or view name, not within the definition of View

Comment: And I was slightly wrong - here's a reference to it not working for [SQL Server 2005](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/queryoptteam/2006/03/24/top-100-percent-order-by-considered-harmful/)